# Unable to center and right align bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to center the 2 rows (temperature and relative humidity) and at same time, they have to be aligned right to each other. However I am not able to achieve that. I tried different combo including pull-right, but in vain. Kindly help.

**Current Wrong Output:**
[image]

**Code:**

```
            <div class="container-fluid h-100 ">
                <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-md-10 h-100 border">

                        <div class="d-flex mt-5 flex-column align-items-center">

                            <div class="p-2 text-center">
                                <h1 class="display-6">Relative Humidity Control</h1>
                                <h3 class="text-muted">Dry Bulb Temperature Calculator - 2</h3>
                                <p class="lead">By <a href="https://parthi2929.github.io/">Parthiban R</a></p>
                            </div>

                        </div>


                        <form>

                            <div class="form-row align-items-center justify-content-center">
                                <label>Dry Bulb Temperature Outside $\ t_1 \ \ $</label>
                                <input class='col-1 border' type="text" value="0" min="0" max="100" step="0.1">
                                <span>$\ ^{\circ}C$</span>
                                <div id="t1-slider-fill"></div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-row align-items-center justify-content-center">
                                <label>Relative Humidity Outside $RH_1 \ \ $</label>
                                <input class='col-1 border' type="text" value="0" min="0" max="100" step="0.1">
                                <span>$\ \%$</span>
                                <div id="rh1-slider-fill"></div>
                            </div>

                        </form>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: You can use column layout for your form. Check out this link: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/forms/#form-grid

Comment: just sketch and upload the expected op image and create a fiddle and upload u r code@Prathiban Rajendran